# Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'Invalid object ID'

Tags: php, mongodb

I had a PHP code which was working nicely, but after I updated Mongo (2.4.4) and mongo driver for php (1.4.2), my code started to generate fatal error.

The line which generates an error is this one

```
$something = new MongoId($some);
```

It generates an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'Invalid object ID'
```

Surely, I can roll back my updates, but is there any idea how I can fix it without rolling back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably this error is because of the wrong `$some` you are providing.
Now you have to pass a correct MongoID to `new MongoId()` constructor.

So `new MongoId('51e1eefc065f908c10000411')` will be ok, but `new MongoId('-6')` will generate your error.

I am using try catch to handle this.

```
try {
    $something = new MongoId($some);
} catch (MongoException $ex) {
    $something = new MongoId();
}
```

So I think that [this documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoid.construct.php) is a little bit outdated and should be changed.

Comment: Thanks, but from where have you got that now you can only pass a correct MongoId